# Error handling for ajax call from jquery jtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, jtable

I have a jtable that has a listAction that calls an action in the controller to return the data for the table.  If the user refreshes the page while the action is in progress its alerts:

[image]

Here is the jtable:

```
$('#cuserTable').jtable({
        title: 'Users',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 15,
        sorting: true,
        ajaxSettings: {
            contentType: 'application/json'
        },

        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("LoadUserTable")'
        },
        .
        .
```

How and where can I add an error handler to display a custom alert (or not even display an alert) if the user refreshes during a table load/reload?

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the error messages for the dialog:

Imagine you are performing an update and you want to return to the dialog message the error occurred:[image: Dialog error message]

```
try{
    //UPDATING
    [...]
    Your update code goes here
    [...]
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    echo json_encoded($jTableResult);
}catch(Exception $ex){
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "NOK";
    $jTableResult['Message'] = "Error while updating the record XYZ";
    echo json_encoded($jTableResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response should have

```
data = {
   Message : "error message",
   Result : "ERROR"
};
$dfd.resolve(data);
```

In jquery jtable, you have to do `$dfd.resolve(data)`